# No response from node server

Tags: node.js

i am sending request to node server i have 3 fields in mongo database named _id,Name and Image.I want to fetch Name and Image filed in key value pairs.I am getting nothing in my response even if there is no error and status code is 200.

Here is my code:

```
router.post('/offers',(req,res) => {

     var obj = req.body.place;

     mongo.connec(function(err){

          if(err){

              console.log("Error:".red +err);
           }
          else{

             var coll = mongo.con.db("Tiffino_db").collection("Offers");

              coll.find({Name:obj},{projection:{_id:0}}).toArray((err,result) => {

                     if(err){
                      console.log("Error:", +err);
                     }

                     else{

                      res.send(result.Name);
                      mongo.con.close();
                     }
              });

           }
     });

 });
```

Please let me know what i did wrong in above code.

**THANKS**

Comment: Should  `mongo.connec` be  `mongo.connect`? I can only think it's your connection that isn't correct

Comment: There is to much wrong with your code. Please see the examples on the mongodb website on how to connect and to see which arguments are passed back by the connect callback. https://docs.mongodb.com/guides/server/read

Answer (score 0):

`result` is an array and does not contain `Name` property.